# Is there robots.txt tester in new Search Console?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console

I've been using the old Search Console despite the new have been around for a while already, but as Google has stopped to support the old version, I have started to transition to the new one.

I started doing technical SEO audit for one project and was really irritated that couldn't find robots.txt tester from the new Webmaster Tools and all Google's tutorials point to the old version (tester still works there) so my question would be that is there even robots.txt in the new version or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look that it is added. When I tried to search the robot.txt using new webmaster help box, it brought the robot.txt but if you see the navigation is pointing to the old webmaster. It still opens the old webmaster for robot.txt test.

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.

Refer the highlighted URL which is still direct me to old webmaster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can still [access the old search console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en).

The head of GSC recently said that he suggests using the old and new search console as they have not done a good job of transferring everything over.